# HTACCESS Rewrite Underscores to Hyphens when file doesn't exist

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, conditional-statements

Ok so I've scoured other people's answered questions, but nothing seems to work?  What I want is to redirect all .html files containing underscores, to the same file name using hyphens UNLESS the underscored file exists.

Here's my current .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*).html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*_.*) $1-$2 [N]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)$ /testing/$1-$2 [L,R=302]
```

The result:
1. When I navigate to /this_file_does_not_exist.html I am rewritten to /testing/this-file-does-not-exist.html

2. When I navigate to /this_file_does_exist.html I am still rewritten to /testing/this-file-does-exist.html

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RewriteCond` needs to be repeated for each `RewriteRule` or contained in a separate rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*_.*?\.html)$ $1-$2 [N]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*?\.html)$ /testing/$1-$2 [L,R=302]
```

Comment: Thanks for your input - unfortunately though, the problem is opposite now.. It's detecting when a file exists but not rewriting when it doesn't..

Comment: I fixed a minor typo. Try again.

Comment: Ah yes I can see what the problem was now after comparing the two.. You are my saviour of the day - Thank you!